# Not able to install python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

while installing python modules , i am getting :

```
C:\Users\sesa384714>python -m pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0408BE30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0408B310>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0408B650>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0408B410>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0408B530>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection?

Comment: Which version of Python do you have?

Comment: Looks like you are behind a firewall that is blocking your connection to pypi.python.org

Comment: Python version that is installed is 3.6.2

Answer (score 0):

such errors occur sometimes when you have slow internet connection,Check your internet connection
or try offline
https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files